# Is jquery keypress function similarly call when data copy using ctrl+c

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
$(param_id).keypress(function() {
   var contents = $(this).val();
   var charlength = contents.length;
                    newwidth =  30;
   $(this).css({width:newwidth+(charlength*7)});
});
```

This is the function I used for extend Input textfield when keyboard key press. But when I copy value using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it does not works. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Ya, this event isn't fired for all keys. You could try: `$(param_id).on('keypress copy cut paste', function(){...});`